# How to disable program switching (alt+tab equivalent) with the mouse?

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to stop programs switching (equivalent of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) in response to mouse gestures. Right now it happens all the time when I use the mouse, I'm not even sure what gestures cause it. I poked around settings but couldn't find anything related, and turning off two finger scrolling didn't stop it. If anyone has any ideas how I could customize that it would be very much appreciated!

(Further info: I use the trackpad on an asus x501a as my mouse. It's a button-less touch-area with right and left click designated in the bottom approximately quarter inch of the area)

Comment: It's work for me when I disable "two finger scroll" in same OS. and I think it's a unexpected behavior for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep two finger scrolling on but COMPLETELY DISABLE THE ALT-TAB FEATURE you'll want to do this, (found at: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211863, the forum post was made to do something slightly different, but can be applied to this issue)

> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
>
> sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins

Open compizconfig-settings-manager with alt-F2, type

> ccsm.

Scroll down to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". Choose the tab "Switcher". Disable the alt-tab and shift-alt-tab key bindings. I went ahead and disabled everything, but you don't have to.

Now this super annoying glitch is gone YAY : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dconf-editor` to disable this feature:

first install:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

then find **scroll-method** and make it as disabled

[image]

Comment: maybe you need to logout/reboot to effect changes